# VBA code to remove a range of cells in a row if a cell's condition criteria is met

Tags: excel, vba

First post on here, so apologies if I'm off on anything.  This site has been extremely useful for me so wanted to toss out a relatively simple question I can't seem to find a direct answer for anywhere.

I'm trying to run a cleanup macro to delete a range of cells in a row based on the condition of Cell `A4` being blank.  I do not want to delete the entire row as there is separate data a few columns over from the range indicated below.

The range of cells I want to delete is from Cell `A4:M4` based on `A4` being blank, as the values in Range A4:D4 are imported static values that vary with each import, and the values in Range E4:M4 are formulaic index cells that respond to the value in cell `A4`.

Any help is appreciated.  Existing code is below:

```
Sub Cleaner()
  Dim rng As Range
  On Error Resume Next
  Set rng = Range("A4:M549").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
  On Error GoTo 0
  rng.Rows.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation of what you want to do seems to be quite different to your actual (non-working code).  If you simply wish to clear range A4:M4 if A4 is blank you could use:

```
Sub cleaner()

    If Range("A4").Value = "" Then
        Range("A4:M4").Clear
    End If

End Sub
```